# Creating large custom shape pads in Autodesk Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, sensor, eaglecad, probe

I'm pretty new to Autodesk Eagle and trying to design a captive soil moisture sensor probe in Eagle. The shape I'm trying to create is:

[image: image of sensor shape]

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with any advice on this.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Asking for open-ended advice is off-topic. Explain what your problem is.

Comment: You can draw shapes using the "polygon" feature. Then assign the appropriate netname to the polygon and if you click ratsnest it will be floodfilled. Use tStop/bStop layers to remove soldermask where required.